# Darker QtColor in stylesheet

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, qtstylesheets

is there a way to make a color darker in a string stylesheet
in normal code i know this works.

```
QColor(QColor(@colorLevelThree).darker(600))
```

but im not entirely sure if theres a way i can do it in the style sheet it self or go about this a different way

```
QPushButton
{
    color: @colorLevelOne;
    background-color: @colorLevelThree;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: QColor(QColor(@colorLevelThree).darker(600));
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
 }
```

Comment: I don't think there's a direct way as the stylesheet is just pared-down CSS, and CSS won't do it. What I do sometimes is use rgba(0,0,0,0.3) or something to set the foreground image opacity, and then lighten/darken it by creating a white or black background under it.

Comment: Hi, did you find any other way than mentioned by @NicolasHolthaus? I'm currently looking for a way how to set read-only edits slightly darker/lighter only by using Qt stylesheet because of light/dark mode support but without success.